# Ejecutar un paquete dtsx desde PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, visual-studio-2019, etl

He intentado hacer esto en PowerShell:

Ruta completa al ejecutable de Visual Studio 2019
$rutaVisualStudio = "C:\Archivos de programa (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Abrir Visual Studio
Inicio-Proceso $rutaVisualStudio

pero solo abre el programa pero no lo ejecuta, agradecería si me pudieran ayudar, muchas gracias de antemano.

Lo que esperaría es ejecutar la tarea que está dentro como en la imagen:

pero todo desde PowerShell o CMD.